# How to categorize posts under Category 1 and Category 2 which are separate lists of categories, and display them as separate lists in widgets

Tags: categories, customization, hierarchical

**Background**

My site is about DIY and 'making' around the house (let's say).

Current version 5.1.1

I use posts for the content on my site which isn't strictly in "blog" (chronological) format in that each page (post) stands by itself. Each page (post) is part of 2 types of catgeories, say Category 1 and Category 2.

- Category 1: Area of the house it's for, e.g. Bedroom, Living Room,
  Kitchen, Office
- Category 2: Type of project/post, e.g. Renovating,
  Customizing, Product Review, Things I would Like To Buy, Tutorial

Each post should (i.e. **will always**) have one category from List 1 and one category from List 2.

An example of an individual post would be:

> How to use the advanced functionality of the A123 food processor to make brownies

The categories would be:

> Category 1: Kitchen, Category 2: Tutorial

Another example:

> ACME Corp just released this lawn-mowing gadget and I can't wait to get my hands on it
>
> Category 1: Garden, Category 2: Things I want to buy

**What I would like to do**

1. On each individual post, in the author/date/categories part I'd like to be able to list out the Category 1 and Category 2 like this:

> Author: admin
>
> Date: 2019/05/01
>
> **Area of the house: *Kitchen***
>
> **Type of project: *Tutorial***

...

> Author: admin
>
> Date: 2019/06/15
>
> **Area of the house: *Garden***
>
> **Type of project: *Things I want to buy***

2. In a widget in the sidebar, I'd like to be able to list the Category 1 and Category 2 in separate sections, e.g.

> AREAS OF THE HOUSE
>
> - kitchen
> - garden
> - bedroom
> - living room
> - office
> - ...

---

> TYPES OF PROJECT
>
> - tutorial
> - customizing
> - things I want to buy
> - product review
> - ....

**Additional info**

It is my own personal website with full admin control so I'm not restricted as to what plugins I can install or files I can edit etc.

I'm using the Twenty Sixteen theme and so far only have a Google Fonts plugin.

If possible I would like it to automatically add new Category1/Category2 items if I create them, but if that's too difficult I am open to adding them manually (there is a finite list and won't be that many, less than 10 of each).

Comment: Separate question, why do you use a plugin to load google fonts?